# How to validate XML value with value displayed in a column of a table

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I am trying to validate a value that I am reading from an XML, the validation I want to perform is to compare the value that I am reading from the XML with the value shown in the table, this validation must be done when loading an XML file, that is to say that at the time of loading the XML file read the value of the XML that I want to compare with the value of the column in the table,  if these values are correct allow the XML file to be loaded otherwise display some alert.

So far I am getting the value that I want to compare in a table for this case we are going to call it `NIT`, to obtain the data I make use of a stored procedure in SQL, I get two values `NumRegister` and `NIT`, but here the only one that I am interested in validating is `NIT`, the code to obtain the data in the table is as follows:

**Showdata.php**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$param = $_POST['param'];  
    switch($param) {
        case '1':
              $query = array();
                include './db/connect.php';
                $USER = utf8_encode($_POST['idUser']);
                $sql = "{call StoredProcedureTest(?)}";
                $params = array($USER);
                $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
                
                if ( $stmt === false) {
                    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
                }
                

                $query = [];
                $query1 = [];

                $lastRegister = '';
                $lastRegister1 = '';
                
                while( $row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1) ) {
                    $record1 = array(
                        "Register"  => $row1['Register']
                        
                    );
                    array_push($query1, $record1);
                }
                
                while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt) ) {
                    
                    if(strcmp($lastRegister, $row['NumRegister']) != 0) {

                    $query[] = [
                        "NumRegister"       => $row['NumRegister'],
                        "NIT"               => $row['Nit']                                 
                    ];
                    
                }
                $index = count($query) - 1;
                if($index < 0) {
                    die('Error: No avalaible');
                }
                
                }
                sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);       
                sqlsrv_close($conn);
                $json = [
                    "success"=> count($query) > 0 ? true : false,
                    "data"=>$query
                ];
                echo json_encode($json);
     
        break;

}


?>
```

Additional as a comment I am making use of the Datatables library which I use to show the data obtained previously in a table, which I do through a function in Javascript, for this I have developed the following function in javascript:

**tablelist.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#example').dataTable( {
        responsive : true,
         ajax : {
             "type": 'POST',
             "url" : './Showdata.php',  
             "dataType": 'JSON',             
             "cache": false,
            "data": {
                 'param' : 1,              
             },
         },
         columns: [          
             {
                 "className":      'details-control',
                 "orderable":      false,
                 "data":           null,
                 "defaultContent": ''
             },
             { "data" : "NumRegister" },
             { "data" : "NIT" },                  
        ],
         order : [[1, 'desc']],
    } );
```

To read the XML node file that I need to validate which corresponds to `NIT`, I am highlighting the following in another PHP script:

**ReadXml.php**

```
$NitNumber = (string)$xml->children('cfdi',true)->Receiver[0]->attributes()['NIT'];
```

In the same PHP script for loading the XML file which I will have to validate with what I commented above and that also after its successful upload is stored in a location, I am making use of the following code:

```
$fileXML = $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['name'];
$pathXML = "//FILEALL/XML/";


if(move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['tmp_name'], $pathXML . $fileXML)){
echo 'Upload Success';  
}
```

So in summary what I need to validate is the value that I am reading in the XML which is assigned to the variable `$NitNumber` with the value shown in the table as I mention at the beginning of my question, is there something additional that I need to complete this validation ?

**Update 1:**

In order to advance a little in the solution of this problem I have decided to add a button in the table where it shows me the data that I am getting from the stored procedure, this button will open a modal window that will contain a tag that will show the value that I want to validate with the XML and additional this window will also contain an XML file upload button.

The code I used to display the modal window is as follows:

```
<!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="ModalUploadXML" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" >
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle" style="color: #FFFFFF;">ADD XML</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true" style="color: #FFFFFF;">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="lblNit" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Nit Company:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNitCompany" disabled>
                        </div>
                     </div>

       <form action="" id="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">File XML:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="XmlToUpload" class="btn" accept=".xml" onchange="ValidateFiles(), validation()" required="">
              </div>
          </div>
    
        </div>        

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Back</button>
            <button type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-success" value="submit" disabled onclick="clickSend(this)">Upload File</button>
          </div>
      </form>

            </div>
      <div class="upload-msg"></div>
          </div>
</div>
```

If you look closely at the tag in which I want to show the `Nit` from the stored procedure corresponds to `txtNitCompany`, which I am trying to show but it tells me that it is undefined

[image]

In my file `tablelist.js` I have assigned in a global variable the value of the `txtNitCompany` tag as follows:

```
var NitCompanyG = $("#txtNitCompany"). val();
```

Where later in my file `ReadXml.php` I have sent by `POST` the `NITValue` variable to the `txtNitCompany` tag as follows:

```
$NITValue= $_POST["txtNitCompany "];
```

To then perform the validation of comparing the value of the XML file with the value of the tag, I have this as follows using the code that I add at the beginning of the question only this time I add the validation:

```
if($NITNumber == $NITValue){
$fileXML = $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['name'];
$pathXML = "//FILEALL/XML/";
if(move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['tmp_name'], $pathXML . $fileXML)){
echo 'Upload Success';  
}
}
```

I've reached this point but with an undefined variable, something I need to add to avoid the undefined variable?

**Update 2:**

Possibly I have not been entirely clear in this question, but here I will try to explain it in the best way.

The initial objective of the question is to validate the XML value with the value shown in the column of a table. To solve this I have obtained the value that I want to validate from a stored procedure and I show it in the JS table. Additionally on the other side or for the other validation I have read the XML file to obtain the value that I am interested in validating.

Seeing that I do not receive much attention to my question and with the intention of looking for a desperate solution to my problem I have added update 1, where I have created a modal window in which I want to show the value that is in the table. But in this case when I want to show it in the label of the modal window it generates an indefinite variable.

Adding a modal window does not mean that this can be a solution to my problem, it is only part of a solution that I am proposing to validate the value of an XML with value that I am obtaining from the stored procedure.

**Update 3:**

I will continue trying to explain it in much more detail even if my comment is vague, it is correct that I want to show the data in a label of my modal window where this data comes from a table in database, this is nothing is part of a possible solution that I want to raise since it is not possible for me to validate the value shown in the column of the table as I commented at the beginning.

The only value that is relevant and that I am interested in validating is the one that corresponds to `NIT` in my js file called `tablelist.js.`

I have not misinterpreted anything because if it is correct that the value comes from a database table for this reason I make use of the file `showdata.php` where I execute a stored procedure to obtain data.

What I would like to send to the user is a notification where the case is that the condition is not met that the value obtained from the XML together with the value I am getting from the data table is not the same, indicate through an alert, but if the files match allow the upload of the documents.

Comment: _"with an undefined variable"_ I hope you understand that this is a very insufficient description of your problem. It's still unclear what the essence of your question is? Maybe you can include a short but self contained sentence describing the whole problem? So that people can help you without needing to guess the situation from a few scattered and incomplete code fragments.

Comment: @inwerpsel I have added a new update to my question in which I have tried as much as possible to be as detailed with what you want me to explain in your comment, I hope it will be of help

Comment: It's still vague. You keep mentioning you need to display data that is in a table. Which is a database table, I suppose, which makes sense. However it's hard to see how the whole part about the JS data table is relevant. Maybe you misinterpreted an assignment, and thought the value needs to be inside a JS data table before being validated (instead of database table)? That doesn't make sense if you need to prevent the file being processed on upload.

Comment: Or do you want to give feedback to the user, saying which item in the JS data table was invalid in the last upload?

Comment: Sorry, its a very big description! I wanted to help but a shorter problem description will invite a lot of attention.

Comment: @inwerpsel I have added a description answering all the possible questions I have and I have tried as much as possible that my comment is not vague, I hope this time it can help.

Answer (score 0):

You did not include your best attempt at solving this, so it's not possible to provide a code answer. It's also unclear to me what is the exact problem causing you to not be able to proceed implementing this. However I can roughly answer your question.

> ..., is there something additional that I need to complete this validation?

Not much it seems. You already have the code to upload the XML file and get its NIT attribute. You could reuse the code and stored procedure already used for displaying the table's data. Then just loop through the input XML data and check each one for validity against the database results, before proceeding to save the data and persist the file.

### More detailed help

This seems to be a problem experienced in an existing code base with a number of own implementations that are not shared here, or just fragments of them.

If you want to get people to solve a problem of this complexity for you (I mean this many moving parts and implementation details), **you'll have to share the full code** you're currently trying, so that other people can run it. Please create a public Github repo, or something similar. An SO question is not the right place to share large amounts of code directly. Please just link to it here.

If that's not possible, maybe SO is not the right place for this question.